# How I can make the JTable ignore the enter key?

Tags: java, jtable, key, defaultbutton

I have set a default button action in my JFrame, but it isnt executed when I am focused in the JTable.

How can I make the JTable ignore the enter key so the form can execute the default button?

Edit: A little more info: The inside of my JFrame is dynamic, it can have different components according to some status: sometime it will have an insert and update buttons, other time it can have a select button.
According to the status, different buttons can be selected as the default button.
The JTable is a generic component used in various frames - it dont even know if tere are buttons, it is there only to have one of this lines selected.
All the pieces put together (jtable, buttons, etc), the default button defined, I want it to be triggered when Enter is pressed, not the column of the JTable changing to other columns.

Comment: could you explain this a bit more ?

Comment: And maybe add some relevant code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)
                                   .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "none");
```

Let's split this line of code up into two steps.

**Step 1:**

```
table.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
```

Every JComponent has a few `InputMaps`. An `InputMap` is basically a way of mapping `KeyStrokes` to actions.

The `getInputMap()` method takes an argument `condition`, which can be one of three values, `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`, `WHEN_FOCUSED` and `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT`. These are constants declared in the `JComponent` class, and correspond to the different states a component can be in. A `JComponent` has an `InputMap` for each state. So there is a different `InputMap` for a component that is focused than when it isn't focused but is inside a window that is.

-- *Note that calling `getInputMap()` without arguments is just a convenience method for `getInputMap(WHEN_FOCUSED)`.* --

**Step 2:**

```
.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "none");
```

Now that we have the right `InputMap`, we want to put something into it right!? So what do we put in it? Well, it's a map so it needs a **key** and a **value**.

In an `InputMap` the **key** is a `KeyStroke`, in this case we have specified the ENTER key by calling `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER")`.

The **value** is a `String` that gives the name of an `Action`.

An `InputMap` is usually used in conjunction with an `ActionMap`. The **value** in an `InputMap` is the **key** in an `ActionMap`. We provided our `InputMap` with the **value** `"none"`, and since there is no `Action` called `"none"` contained in the `ActionMap`, nothing will happen.

So, all in all, we've told the `JTable` to **do nothing** when the ENTER key is pressed.

More info on Key Bindings [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Is this canceling the ENTER key in the JTable? I will try it and see

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Done :) I hope what I've written is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

remember this is Not just the Table, if you're editing within a Table the Editor will be the one listening to Key Stores and Not Table.
so its a bigger problem than just table.
[Read about default key bindings](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/)

Comment: My table will not have editing, the fact is that I want the active default button being executed, so it can act according the selected JTable row.